# pluralize or not "How was your thanksgiving holiday(s)? "

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Is it proper to ask

> *How was your Thanksgiving holidays?*

Because we had 5 days of holidays and Thanksgiving day was one day among those.

Do I say:

> *How **were** your holidays?*

Is the usage of *holiday* singular or plural?

Comment: Thanksgiving is a singular holiday.  The Christmas season is generally plural (in AmE) because it encompasses multiple holidays, including New Year's

Comment: "A holiday", at least in British English, is often used as a synonym vacation, "How was your Thanksgiving holiday?" can be read as "How was your Thanksgiving vacation?"

I feel holiday is pluralised in this context so as not to imply a vacation, even when talking about a single day holiday. Using "was" with "holidays" plural is incorrect though

Comment: "How was your Thanksgiving holiday?" can mean "vacation period" in American English as well. Also, several holidays around and including New Years, including several different religions, are collectively pluralized "*the* holidays": "Are you going home for the holidays?" "Did you enjoy the holidays?"

Answer (score -1):

"How was your holiday?" or "How were your holidays?" if they had "a long weekend".